# show images from host-web in add-in (app web) CORS problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, image, cors

I need to display images from the host web in an add-in, without the user necessarily having visited the host web. Is this achievable? The images are stored as item attachments in a list, and I've been using JSOM to retrieve the source url.

I've concluded that there has to be some CORS problem when I've been testing. The image sources are working, but images doesn't display until I have navigated to the host web. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because you are directly going into the app without going into host web (access token won't be available in browser for fetching the image).

In our case, we directed the user first into the host web (to a page with script editor) and from there redirected to the app. This solved our issue.